# Shadowmere fell off a cliff and died. How do I get him back?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was riding Shadowmere near Alftand and I accidentally fell into that canyon near the abandoned tower. The fall was enough to kill Shadowmere.

I have done a lot of quests and other things such as fast travel, waiting, and sleeping so I am wondering if that interrupted his respawn. Also if I come back to that point before he respawns, is that bad?

Can Shadowmere just go away and never come back after his death?

I tried waiting in-game for 11 days in Solitude and then returning to Shadowmere's death point, but it did not work.

I do not want to use script commands because I consider that 'cheating' and I don't want to cheat.

Comment: He got killed for me somehow about 2/3 way through, and I never got him back. So it is possible.

Answer (score 12):

According to the wiki, you should wait [15-20 days](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Shadowmere) for Shadowmere to respawn at the place he died.

Comment: So when you'll fast travel after that he should 'spawn' right behind you, or do you have to see him alive before he starts doing it again?

Answer (score 3):

I lost Shadowmere while fighting a dragon. He attacked while I was riding. I dismounted to show him what was up and got hit by one of those fly over breath attacks they do. i turned to watch him and saw Shadowmere flying of into the distance. It sucked to lose my buddy but it looked pretty funny. Anyway, around fifteen days later I did a fast travel and there he was just waiting for me. I was pretty happy to see him again. He is pretty awesome!

Comment: The same information has been posted 5 months ago.

Answer (score 0):

This wiki article claims:

> If Shadowmere is killed, waiting in a main city for 10 days then
>   returning to where he died should respawn him on both PC and console
>   versions.

source: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Shadowmere_(Skyrim)

Comment: IIRC, it's more like 30 days and he respawned at the dark brotherhood.  ymmv.

Comment: @Rotenegg The same source also had this to say: _If you run off a small cliff, (enough to kill a horse, but not you), Shadowmere will die. He can also die from any other cause of damage, weapons, magic, etc. If Shadowmere dies on the PC version of Skyrim, a new one can be spawned at the player's location by using the console command, (without quotes), "player.placeatme 0009CCD7". Another option is to target Shadowmere's body and typing resurrect in the console command box._

Comment: I'd like to point out that using `placeatme` on unique NPCs is horrible advice most of the time, as it will spawn another copy of the NPC in question, leading to possible bugs. The correct way is to target deceased NPC or creature (use `prid RefID` if the body is unreachable), then type the following commands: `disable`, `enable`, `kill`, `resurrect`, `moveto player` should work without having avoidable side effects.

Comment: So glad I don't play this on a console!